# Reading frame configuration from file

Tags: init-file, frames, desktop, session

I'm just trying my hands on emacs lisp.  So far I've had some luck, but
I'm stuck trying to load my frames configuration into a list.

Here's what I'm trying to do...
I am saving frames configuration (all currently open frames) like so

```
(defun save-all-frames ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((config (current-frame-configuration)))
    (with-temp-buffer
      (insert
       (format "%s" config))
      (if (file-exists-p framegeometry-file)
          (when (file-writable-p framegeometry-file)
            (write-file framegeometry-file)))
      ))
  )
```

where `framegeometry-file` points to `"~/.emacs.d/frameconfig.el"`

Now this works fine...but I do not know how to read it back
into a list so that I can traverse through it and create frames
with the configuration. I'm thinking of using `set-frame-configuration` to
restore the configuration read from the file.

Any help or pointers in the right direction will be really appreciated.

Comment: Considering that `(current-frame-configuration)` returns un`read`able objects, this approach has no chance of working. You might want to look at code in `desktop.el`, which comes with Emacs, which does plenty of things including saving of the frame configuration.

Comment: Thank you.  Right now I've progressed to a point where I can restore the layout and  buffers, but the buffer which was in focus when I exited emacs is not put back in focus.  But if I call `load-file` on my desktop file, it works.  So I will look into doing that instead of calling desktop-read.

Comment: What @DoMiNeLa10 said. See library `frameset.el`, which is what `desktop.el` uses for saving and restoring frames.

Comment: Following up on my question.. I've managed to do what I set out to, using frameset-save and frameset-restore functions.  With these, I'm able to restore all frame and buffer configuration including restoring buffers to their frames/windows and restoring all state before Emacs was killed.  And this works irrespective of how Emacs is launched i.e. daemon or standalone process.

Comment: @WilsonAlmeida can you post an answer to your question if you managed to figure it out?

Comment: @DoMiNeLa10  : I would love to post it, but it's an ugly hack :)  I am not sure if it works outside of my setup.  When I get some time, I'm going to clean it up and put it in a separate library as opposed to the config.org file that it currently resides in.  That way I can upload this library file instead of posting a hack which may not make sense to others.  Cheers :)

Comment: If you want a couple of pointers to help you out with elisp library development, just ask.